# Use Autoform with a custom object

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

There is any way to use autoform to edit/update a plain javascript object (no Mongo.Collection/Server call)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is. See the autoform docs [here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#non-collection-forms) on how you can do it.

Comment: Yes! Previously I've tried with the documentation without luck.... until now! I listen the form "submit" event, and use this (https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/blob/master/api.md#autoformgetformvaluesformidclient) to get the data. Thank you!